# How do I turn off relative positioning?

Tags: css, wordpress

http://mikroautobusunuoma.org/

The positioning of the slider on the page is screwed up in all 3 major browsers. By turning off 'position:relative' (Element style) It seems to fix the issue (In Firebug, etc.) I have searched every file on the server and cannot find where the element style is though. I used Agent Ransack to search multiple terms to try to find the line of code, to no avail.

I am lost as where to go from here.

This is a wordpress site with a built-in-theme Jquery Slider.

```
    <div id="featured-slider" style="background-image: none; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

    element.style {
       background-image: none;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: The styles are in your `style.css` file on the lines 186, 355, and 415. Firebug told me. `:P`

Comment: You are refering to inline styles. These styles are either hard-coded into the HTML file, or added via JavaScript, e.g. jQuery's `.css()` method. They are *not* in your CSS files.

Comment: That's not where the element.style comes from.  Element.style is not in the CSS, but is how Firebug displays elements that are applied directly to an element.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do `position:static !important;`

This will overwrite any existing CSS and inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Element.style is the inline style.

If you add `!important` it will overwrite the inline style but you will need to know the class/id, unless you can just change the inline style.

Comment: I searched every file on the server. That inline style doesn't exist. Not in CSS form anyways..lol

Comment: Right, because element.style is the style for that particular element. When you are using Firebug, it will show up as "element.style" when you select your div, the style will be whatever is in "style" attribute, which you have: "background-image: none; position: relative; overflow: hidden;"